# How to make left and right side of fieldset dissapear(css/html)

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner In html and css.

How remove the sides of the fieldset border?

I have tried:
border: 1px 0 1px 0
In css. But it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```css
fieldset {
  /* this sets the color of the borders on the block axis,
     top and bottom in a left-to-right, top-to-bottom
     language such as English to a color of #f90: */
  border-block-color: #f90;
  /* this sets the border of the elements' inline-axis
     left and right in a left-to-right language such as
     English to:
     border-width: 0;
     border-style: none;
     border-color: transparent; */
  border-inline: 0px none transparent;

  /* irrelevant, just for aesthetics */
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: clamp(20em, 60vw, 1000px);
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <label>Input One:
    <input type="text">
  </label>
  <label>Input Two:
    <input type="text">
  </label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <label>Input Three:
    <input type="text">
  </label>
  <label>Input Four:
    <input type="text">
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cafd52g1/1/).

References:

- [`border-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-block).
- [`border-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-inline).